# Azure mobile service token expiration life

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Here is my code that i am using for google authentication in xamarin forms development, after authentication i'm getting sid and token token, but token life is hardly 1 hour. Is there any way to increase the expiration time of token. If anybody knows please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
var user = await DependencyService.Get<IAuthentication>()
                 .LoginAsync(azureService.MobileService, provider);
if (user == null)
    return;
else
{
    await GetCurrentUserDetail(provider, Settings.AuthToken);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot increase the token life because it is tied to the token life of the Google id_token that is acquired by the mobile app backend during login. However, you do have the option to refresh this token so that you don't need to re-authenticate every hour. You can do so using the [RefreshTokenAsync](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/05ba43da2ee56f6bf9f2a5fbe682fb325ef20f1b/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/MobileServiceClient.cs#L397) method in recent versions of the client SDK.

More background information can be found here: https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Please accept Chris's post if it answered your question :)

Comment: I have followed the link and make request to backend "/.auth/refresh" but i am getting this "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." from postman. I am using Microsoft authentication token. Do you have any idea why this is happening and where we have to change.

Comment: I have add this line of code too request.Headers["x-access_type"] = "offline";